# jquery tocify wrong order

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tableofcontents, jquery-tocify-js

Iam using Tocify https://github.com/gfranko/jquery.tocify.js to make a TOC on some contents at a site. It works great, however I have run into a problem with the way Tocify is ordering my content.
I think the best way to show it, is with this picture:[image]

Testeoverskrift 5 comes before Testeoverskrift 6 in my query (which is the way it should be), but Tocify places Testeoverskrift after Testeoverskrift 6.
The expected result would be that Tocify would place Testeoverskrift 5 at the same level as Testeoverskrift 9, and below Testeoverskrift 10.

Any suggestions to what iam doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you mind creating an issue on [github](https://github.com/gfranko/jquery.tocify.js/issues?direction=desc&sort=created&state=closed)?  Also, it would be helpful if you had a public test page or a jsfiddle/jsbin example.  Thanks!

**Note:** I wrote Tocify

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for the quick reply, i haven't been able to recreate the error in a jsfiddle. The site where iam coding, unfortunately can't been visited from the public. Since I can't recreate the error in a jsfiddle, I must have an error on my site, note related to Tocify. I will try to create the error in  jsfiddle, and then create an issue on github, if I succeed. Can you tell me where in the Tocify css my own css i have a collision that I think causes the error with the selected heding (the blue expands over the div as it can be seen above).

Comment: Your CSS error is most likely on line 53 and not setting a 0 margin:  
.nav-list > li > a, .nav-list .nav-header {
    margin: 0px;
}